# Codeigniter -> File Upload Path | Folder Create

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

Currently I have the following:

`$config['upload_path'] = 'this/path/location/';`

What I would like to do is create the following controller but I am not sure how to attack it!!

```
$data['folderName'] = $this->model->functionName()->tableName;

$config['upload_path'] = 'this/'.$folderName.'/';
```

How would I create the `$folderName?` dictionary on the sever?

**Jamie:**

Could I do the following?

```
if(!file_exists($folderName))
{

  $folder = mkdir('/location/'$folderName);

   return $folder; 
}
else
{
 $config['upload_path'] = $folder; 
}
```

Comment: I'm not following - Wouldn't you already have access to that value via `$data['folderName']`?

Comment: Yes Colin but I need to somehow incorporate mkdir or similar to create the folder on the server.

Comment: You might want to clarify that you're asking how to create a directory named `$data['folderName']` - I interpreted your question differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

am not sure what they are talking about by using the file_exist function since you need to check if its the directory ..

```
$folderName = $this->model->functionName()->tableName;
$config['upload_path'] = "this/$folderName/";
if(!is_dir($folderName))
{
   mkdir($folderName,0777);
}
```

please note that :

1. i have added the **permission** to the folder so that you can upload files to it.
2. i have removed the `else` since its not useful here ( as @mischa noted )..

Comment: Works without the if is that ok?

Comment: the if will check the to see if the folder is exists or not , and if its exist then it will not create it nor throw any warning or so..

Comment: You don't need the else clause! If the folder doesn't exit you still want to carry on with upload (after creating the folder).

Comment: You can also you [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check if a directory exists.

Comment: @mischa your right in both .. but from my point of view its better to make your code readable for every one ..

Comment: What does readability have to do with it? With the `else` the code does not work the way it is supposed to work.

Comment: @mischa i got your point .. the `else` is not useful here unless he wanted to do something after he knows that the folder is exist .. i will edit it right a way ..

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct:

```
if(!file_exists($folderName))
{
   mkdir($folderName);
}
else
{
   // Carry on with upload
}
```

Nothing will be uploaded if the folder does not exist! You have to get rid of the else clause.

```
$path = "this/$folderName/";

if(!file_exists($path))
{
   mkdir($path);
}

// Carry on with upload
$config['upload_path'] = $path;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean by 'dictionary', but if you're asking about how to create a variable:

```
$folderName = $this->model->functionName()->tableName;

$config['upload_path'] = "this/$folderName/";
```

---

To add/check the existence of a directory:

```
if(!file_exists($folderName))
{
   mkdir($folderName);
}
else
{
   // Carry on with upload
}
```

Comment: I want to create that $folderName on the server

Comment: When I upload the image I want it to be uploaded into the folder $folderName but this folder does not exists I need to create it.  Possibly doing this before the upload function

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want from your description so here are a few suggestions:

If you need to programmatically create a folder using PHP you can use the mkdir() function, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Also, check out the Codeignitor file helper for reading and writing files:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html

If the folder already exists, you need to make sure the permissions are write-able.  On windows you can right click on the folder, properties, security and edit there.  On Linux you'll want the chmod command.